# How can I find the size of an uploaded file in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload

I am not using carrierwave or paperclip for my file upload. I want to find out the file extension and the size in bytes of a file that the user has uploaded? Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
File.size(doc.filename)
```

Just throw the name of the file into the curly brackets and you should be set.

If you want KB/MB use:

```
number_to_human_size(File.size(doc.filename))
```

EDIT:

You can use the exact path or Pathname

```
1.9.3p125 :005 > x=Pathname.new("/usr/bin/ruby")
 => #<Pathname:/usr/bin/ruby> 
1.9.3p125 :006 > File.size(x)
 => 5488
```

For extension:

```
File.extname("test.rb")         #=> ".rb"
```

Comment: How about getting the extension? Is it best to just split the filename at the '.'?

Comment: To use `number_to_human_size` you need to add `include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper` to your class.

Comment: For those having trouble testing this in the console, helper methods are outside of the scope of console. http://archive.railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=25150

Comment: Why do you use string interpolation when not required? File.size(doc.filename) works fine, you don't need the "#{}" wrapper.

Comment: Good point Andy. Updated. What can I say, this is a very old answer ;P

Answer (score 11):

```
params[:file].size
File.extname(params[:file].original_name)
```

or `params[:file].original_name.match(/\.(\S*)$/).try(:"[]",1)`

Comment: params[:file].size is nice and easy!

Comment: how we know the size type? whether it is in kb or byte ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ruby's File class methods.

- [File.size](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-size)
- [File.extname](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-extname)